# show error: "Unknown revision action: 20" with vss2git

Tags: git, visual-sourcesafe

I run vss2git (by Trevor Robinson), but there are some problems. I reviewed the code, the error is in

*vss2git/VssLogicalLib/VssRevision.cs*

```
private static VssAction CreateAction(RevisionRecord revision, VssItem item)
```

When the `revision.Action=20` or `revision.Action=21`, will meet the follow code.

```
default:
    throw new ArgumentException("Unknown revision action: " + revision.Action);
```

How can I do this? May I ignore it?

Answer (score 0):

Check history for this file with standard VSS client and see what these action are. Then you can decide if you can ignore them.